# What is the word for daily in relation to day?

Tags: word-usage

If *days* is the plural of day, daily is the ***what*** of day?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's either the **adverbial** or **adjectival** form depending on context. In the sentence

> I do my chores daily.

It's an **adverbial of time** (see [this link](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/adverbials)). Essentially it's a form of the word used to say when or how often something happens, in this case every day.

If, however, you say something like

> I just did my daily chores.

Daily, rather than being an adverb, is an adjective describing your chores. See also [this link](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/about-adjectives-and-adverbs/adjectives-forms).

Although not exactly a 100% reliable method, a good way to figure out which form you're dealing with is replacing the word daily with something else that is only an adverb or only an adjective. For example, I can replace the word with "quickly" in the first sentence but not the second, and I can replace the word with "boring" in the second sentence but not the first, so I know the first is an adverb and the second is an adjective.

Answer (score 0):

The term daily refers to frequency or cadence rather than having a direct relationship to day and no relationship to plurality.
It occurs daily, weekly, monthly. The complete cycle is ten days, ten weeks, ten months.